# Inconsistent parsing of pure negative queries inside brackets

Tags: solr, lucene

These two queries return different results just by adding brackets around the negative query. I fail to understand why the second query returns empty results just by adding brackets.

**Without Brackets:**

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "indent": "true",
      "fq": "-fl_monitoring_channel: 36 AND (title: salesforce)",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1467637035433"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 35541,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [...
```

**With Brackets:**

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "indent": "true",
      "fq": "(-fl_monitoring_channel: 36) AND (title: salesforce)",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1467637344339"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}
```

### After adding debugQuery=true:

I still don't understand what's going on here.
**Without Brackets:**

```
"debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "*:*",
    "querystring": "*:*",
    "parsedquery": "MatchAllDocsQuery(*:*)",
    "parsedquery_toString": "*:*",
    "explain": {
      "brief.1054522": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1070810": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1067146": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1067658": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1112418": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1112426": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1058810": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1070274": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1062330": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "brief.1064650": "\n1.0 = *:*, product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n"
    },
    "QParser": "LuceneQParser",
    "filter_queries": [
      "-fl_monitoring_channel: 36 AND (title: salesforce)"
    ],
    "parsed_filter_queries": [
      "-fl_monitoring_channel:36 +title:salesforc"
    ],
    "timing": {
      "time": 33,
      "prepare": {
        "time": 0,
        "query": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "facet": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "facet_module": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "mlt": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "highlight": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "stats": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "expand": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "debug": {
          "time": 0
        }
      },
      "process": {
        "time": 32,
        "query": {
          "time": 28
        },
        "facet": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "facet_module": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "mlt": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "highlight": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "stats": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "expand": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "debug": {
          "time": 4
        }
      }
    }
```

**With Brackets:**

```
"debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "*:*",
    "querystring": "*:*",
    "parsedquery": "MatchAllDocsQuery(*:*)",
    "parsedquery_toString": "*:*",
    "explain": {},
    "QParser": "LuceneQParser",
    "filter_queries": [
      "(-fl_monitoring_channel: 36) AND (title: salesforce)"
    ],
    "parsed_filter_queries": [
      "+(-fl_monitoring_channel:36) +title:salesforc"
    ],
    "timing": {
      "time": 0,
      "prepare": {
        "time": 0,
        "query": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "facet": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "facet_module": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "mlt": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "highlight": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "stats": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "expand": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "debug": {
          "time": 0
        }
      },
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the query is parsed as (`debugQuery=true`)? The spaces might be messing stuff up...

Comment: Spaces don't affect the result. I checked!

Comment: but debugQuery should show you how the query is parsed - and the difference between the two

Comment: I added the result of adding debugQuery=true in the question.

Comment: Please paste here the results of debug query so we can try to help more. Looking at the query it seems to me that the issue is the space before the 36. How did you verify that it doesn't affect the results?

Comment: Just did that in the question!